# Is it good that Socket.io listens the same port as HTTP does?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

My question is when WebSocket and HTTP listen the same port, will that be a problem? Will WebSocket slow down the HTTP server or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't cause a problem. They need to run on the same port, but the port doesn't have to explicitly be port 80 (which is the default HTTP port). Whatever your Node HTTP server listens on, Socket.io listens to as well. The code below is from the [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) website. As you can see, both the server and Socket.io listen on port 3000.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

This shouldn't cause a problem, because after all it is required. The only other option would be to incorporate an I-frame or allow cross-origin requests. But depending on what kind of Socket.io app and how many connections are concurrently connected determines its efficiency. So it may or may not slow the server down. Unless you have millions of connections and emits, speed probably shouldn't be an issue.